# Outputting the value of a particular span when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a script that detects the particular `<span>` the user clicks on and outputs the value of the contents of that clicked span.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="span-container">
    <span>Lorem</span>
    <span>Ipsum</span>
    <span>Something...</span>
    <span>Something...</span>
    <span>Amet</span>
</div>
```

And my Javascript looks like this:

```
div = document.getElementById("span-container");
spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");

for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
        alert(spans[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Attempting to run this code results in a `Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined` error.

I'm sure giving each span an ID that correlates to its contents like `<span id="lorem">Lorem</span>` would work, but I'm optimistic that a more elegant solution exists.

I'd also like to avoid using jQuery if possible.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate):

```
var div = document.getElementById('span-container');
div.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    if(target.nodeName == 'SPAN') {
        alert(target.innerHTML);
    }
});
```

Comment: Upvoting it since this solution tries to optimize the number of action handlers. Event delegation is always better performant and flexible (No need to put one more action handler if one more span element is added).

Answer (score 1):

## Wrapping it

The problem is, `i` has changed by the time the user click on it. Use a self-executing function or eventListener

```
div = document.getElementById("span-container");
spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");

for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    (function (j) {
        spans[j].onclick = function() {
            alert(spans[j].innerHTML);
        }
    }(i));
}
```

```js
div = document.getElementById("span-container");
spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");

for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    (function (j) { // Receives as j
        spans[j].onclick = function() {
            alert(spans[j].innerHTML);
        }
    }(i)); // Passes in i
}
```

```html
<div id="span-container">
    <span>Lorem</span>
    <span>Ipsum</span>
    <span>Something...</span>
    <span>Something...</span>
    <span>Amet</span>
</div>
```

---

## Using `this`

`this` will refer to the element clicked and is probably the best way to do this:

```
div = document.getElementById("span-container");
spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");

for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
        alert(this.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

```js
div = document.getElementById("span-container");
spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");

for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
        alert(this.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="span-container">
    <span>Lorem</span>
    <span>Ipsum</span>
    <span>Something...</span>
    <span>Something...</span>
    <span>Amet</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[The problem here is the wrong use of a closure variable in a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake)

But I think in this case you can use addEventListener

```js
div = document.getElementById("span-container");
spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");

function spanClickHandler() {
  alert(this.innerHTML);
}

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].addEventListener('click', spanClickHandler, false);
}
```

```html
<div id="span-container"> <span>Lorem</span>
  <span>Ipsum</span>
  <span>Something...</span>
  <span>Something...</span>
  <span>Amet</span>

</div>
```

---

or just use `this.innerHTML` as `this` inside the event handler refers to the span element

```
spans[i].onclick = function () {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
}
```

- [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Using `.onclick` isn't the problem and `addEventListener` isn't the solution. It's using the `this` keyword to refer to the element clicked. I feel that you are emphasizing on the wrong topic

Comment: @vihan1086 the addEventListner is used because having an anonymous function in a loop is not a good practice... though you can use the named function `onclick`... also the using `this` in the `onclick` is already added as a solution... Using `addEventListner ` or not is a matter of practice....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` for the current element.

Try this code:

```
div = document.getElementById("span-container");
spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");

for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
        alert(this.innerHTML);
    }
}
```